# include-ing signatures of nested structures

Tags: module, sml, signature, smlnj

In `module-a.sig`, I have:

```
signature FOO = sig
  structure Bar: sig
    end
end
```

which corresponds to `module-a.sml`, which looks like:

```
structure Foo: FOO = struct
  structure Bar = struct 
    end
  end
```

In `module-b.sml`, I need to write something that extends all of the types in `Foo`. It looks like this:

```
structure Baz: BAZ = struct 
  structure Bat = struct 
    open Foo.Bar
    end
  end
```

How can I write a signature for `Baz` that shows that it's got all of `FOO.Bar` inside of it? If `Bar` were top level, with a signature named `BAR`, I would write:

```
signature BAZ = sig
  structure Bat: sig
    include BAR
  end
end
```

but I can't do that here, because there is no top-level signature named `BAR`. I tried:

```
signature BAZ = sig
  structure Bat: sig
    include FOO.Bar
  end
end
```

but that caused a syntax error. I also tried:

```
signature BAZ = sig
  include FOO
  structure Bat: sig
    include Bar
  end
end
```

but that gave me "Error: unbound signature: Bar".

Can this be done? Can I avoid writing out a top-level signature for `Bar` somewhere?